# Como mudar o valor de um objeto no .json em python

Tags: json, python

como que eu faço para mudar o valor de um objeto no .json em python (sem rescrever ele todo)?
Ex:

```
{
    "Nome": "Henrique Antônio de Oliveira"
    "Cidade": "São Paulo"
    "Estado": "São Paulo"
    "Idade": "23"
    "Número do Pedido:": "457835"
}
```

Como eu faria pra mudar a idade dele, sem rescrever a .json inteira? Desde então eu agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alterando o valor pela chave. Exemplo:

```
import json

j = json.loads('{"Nome": "Fulano", "Idade": "23"}')
j['Idade'] = '12'
```

#### [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/IfknLM)